# dynamically adding members to coffee-script object

Tags: coffeescript

So currently I have an object which looks like this

```
module.exports = class Book extends events.EventEmitter

    constructor: ->

        @books = 
            a: new small_book('aaa')
            b: new small_book('bbb')
            c: new small_book('ccc')
            d: new small_book('ddd')

    update: (pair, callback) ->
        @books[pair].update_book()
        @emit 'update'
```

However, What I would like to be doing is this,

```
 pairs = 
     a: 'aaa'
     b: 'bbb'
     c: 'ccc'
     d: 'ddd'

 module.exports = class Book extends events.EventEmitter

     constructor: ->       
        for each pair in pairs 
            @books[pair] = new small_book(pairs[pair])
```

or basically just going through my list and adding exactly as many pairs are in the list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> Comprehensions can also be used to iterate over the keys and values in an object. Use `of` to signal comprehension over the properties of an object instead of the values in an array.
>
> ```
> yearsOld = max: 10, ida: 9, tim: 11
>
> ages = for child, age of yearsOld
>   "#{child} is #{age}"
> ```

So if you want loop over an object, do it like this:

```
constructor: ->
    @books = { }       
    for k, v of pairs 
        @books[k] = new small_book(v)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/GnVXa/

Comment: should I be doing @books, instead of Book? also isn't v just a counter? so it should be `new small_book(k)`? I want books to have the same key names as pair. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you'd want `@books[k]` as in my update, sorry I misread your question. You don't want `new small_book(k)` though, `k` will be the keys (`'a'`, `'b'`, ...), the values (`'aaa'`, `'bbb'`, ...) will be in `v`. If you use `for e, i in array`, then `e` would be the array element and `i` would be a counter, `for ... of` and `for ... in` behave differently since they're iterating over different sorts of things.